# PyCharm Pro dont let me start Django project, yesterday everything was fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm

I am trying to start a Django project, but pycharm wont let me do it. Yesterday everything was fine. I have already reinstalled pip3 and python3. What should i do?
Here are the screenshots:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

[image: screenshot 4]

```
The following command was executed:

pip install Django

The exit code: 2
The error output of the command:



Usage:   
  /home/nikita/PycharmProjects/djangoProject4/venv/bin/python -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  /home/nikita/PycharmProjects/djangoProject4/venv/bin/python -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  /home/nikita/PycharmProjects/djangoProject4/venv/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  /home/nikita/PycharmProjects/djangoProject4/venv/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  /home/nikita/PycharmProjects/djangoProject4/venv/bin/python -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --build-dir

Non-zero exit code (2)
```